# Database locked SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery() throws an exception

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

My database (SQLITE) is locked at the Line SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery() .
I tried to use the command Using But it didnt work.
help me please to solve my problem.

```vb
Try
    SQLcnn.ConnectionString = gFournisseurDonneesCie
    SQLcnn.Open()
    SQLcnnCompl.ConnectionString = gFournisseurComplementCie
    SQLcnnCompl.Open()
    dstDivers.Locale = gCultureInfo

    With SQLcommand
        .Connection = SQLcnn
        .CommandText = "UPDATE Produit SET PrixDetailProduit = ?, PrixCoutantProduit = ?, EscompteSurVente = ?, CommVenteProduit = ?, QuanEnMainProduit = ?, " &
                 " QuanMinProduit = ?, QuanACommProduit = ? WHERE CodeIDProduit = ?"
        .Parameters.Clear()
        paramCol = .Parameters
    End With
    With SQLada
        .SelectCommand = New SQLiteCommand("SELECT CodeIDProduit,PrixCoutantProduit,PrixDetailProduit,EscompteSurVente,CommVenteProduit,QuanEnMainProduit,QuanMinProduit,QuanACommProduit FROM GestionPrixListeProduits WHERE CodeIDGestPrixProd = ?", SQLcnnCompl)
        .SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strCodeIDDivers", strCodeIdenGestPrix)
        dstDivers.Clear()
        .Fill(dstDivers, "GestionPrixListeProduits")
    End With
    For Each drwRangee In dstDivers.Tables("GestionPrixListeProduits").Rows
        With paramCol
            .AddWithValue("PrixDetailProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("PrixDetailProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("PrixCoutantProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("PrixCoutantProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("EscompteSurVente_New", drwRangee.Item("EscompteSurVente"))
            .AddWithValue("CommVenteProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("CommVenteProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("QuanEnMainProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("QuanEnMainProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("QuanMinProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("QuanMinProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("QuanACommProduit_New", drwRangee.Item("QuanACommProduit"))
            .AddWithValue("CodeIDProduit_Orig", drwRangee.Item("CodeIDProduit"))
        End With

        intRowsAffected = SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next
```

Comment: Well may not be related to you problem, one thing I see is it looks like your adding the parameters again to SQLcommand on every iteration of the for loop.  Probably be better served to add the parameters once when your up where your setting the command text etc, then update the values in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one data adapter to retrieve the data and save it, e.g.

```vb
Dim sourceConnectionString = "source connection string here"
Dim destinationConnectionString = "destination connection string here"
Dim selectStatement = "SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM SourceTable"
Dim updateStatement = "UPDATE DestinationTable SET Name = @Name, Description = @Description WHERE Id = @Id"

Using sourceConnection As New SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString),
      destinationConnection As New SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString),
      selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, sourceConnection),
      updateCommand As New SqlCommand(updateStatement, destinationConnection),
      adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand) With {.UpdateCommand = updateCommand}
    With updateCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Name")
        .Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Description")
        .Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id")
    End With

    Dim table As New DataTable

    'Retrieve the data.
    adapter.Fill(table)

    'Make every row ready to be updated.
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        row.SetModified()
    Next

    'Save the data.
    adapter.Update(table)
End Using
```

If the source and destination tables are in the same database then you only need one connection string and one connection object and you should also call `Open` on the connection before calling `Fill`. There's no need to call `Close` as that will happen implicitly at the `End Using` line, where the connection is disposed. If the tables are in different databases then there's no need to call `Open` either, as `Fill` and `Update` will both implicitly open the connection if it's not already open and then close it again afterwards.

The example code I have provided is obviously for SQL Server but the principle is the same no matter the database or ADO.NET provider.

Comment: Hello, Thank But i have a DataSet for to retrieve the data.
Here are my variable declarations

        `Dim SQLcnn As New SQLiteConnection
        Dim SQLcnnCompl As New SQLiteConnection
        Dim SQLada As New SQLiteDataAdapter
        Dim dstDivers As New DataSet
        Dim drwRangee As DataRow
        Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand
        Dim SQLreader As SQLiteDataReader
        Dim SQLcommand As New SQLiteCommand
        Dim paramCol As SQLiteParameterCollection  `

Comment: And what does a DataSet contain? Could it be... DataTables? What do you think dstDivers.Tables("GestionPrixListeProduits") is? You're already calling Fill in the code you posted so what's the problem?

Comment: my problem is SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery() throws an exception database locked

Comment: when I change my database to access everything works

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` wouldn't be throwing an exception if you weren't calling it in the first place. Your problem is that you're doing the wrong thing and that is creating a problem. Stop doing the wrong thing and the problem goes away.